# Django удаляет сессии при выходе с аккаунта?

Tags: python, django, сессия

Реализовал просмотр последних товаров через сессии. Когда авторизован товары показываются как надо. Но стоит мне выйти из аккаунта, возникает ошибка **KeyError at / 'recently_viewed'**. Я полагаю, что сессии при логауте очищаются и, соответственно, ключ **recently_viewed** удален. Вот и возникает ошибка. Это можно как-то исправить и сохранять сессию даже при выходе из аккаунта? Вот функция логаута:

```
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

Представление товара:

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'app/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_detail'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'product_slug'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        global recently_viewed_products
        recently_viewed_products = None

        if 'recently_viewed' not in request.session:
            request.session['recently_viewed'] = [self.kwargs['product_slug']]
        else:
            if self.kwargs['product_slug'] in request.session['recently_viewed']:
                request.session['recently_viewed'].remove(self.kwargs['product_slug'])
                request.session['recently_viewed'].append(self.kwargs['product_slug'])
            else:
                request.session['recently_viewed'].append(self.kwargs['product_slug'])

        recently_viewed_products = Product.objects.filter(slug__in=request.session['recently_viewed']).order_by('last_visit')
        request.session.modified = True
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Product.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['product_slug']).update(views=F('views') + 1)
        self.object.last_visit = datetime.now()
        self.object.save()
        context['recently'] = recently_viewed_products
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(draft=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял немного функцию логаута. Теперь она выглядит вот так:

```
def logout_user(request):
    your_data = request.session.get('recently_viewed', None)
    current_expiry = request.session.get('_session_expiry')
    logout(request)
    if your_data:
        request.session['recently_viewed'] = your_data
        if current_expiry:
            request.session['_session_expiry'] = current_expiry
    return redirect('home')
```

1. Получаю из сессии ключ просмотренных товаров. Если такого ключа нет, то передаю None.
2. Получаю время жизни сессии.
3. Логаут
4. Делаю проверку. Если your_data что-то содержит(не None), то в сессии создаю новый ключ с таким же названием recently_viewed. Передаю данные для этого ключа из your_data.
5. Далее такая же проверка, как выше. Только тут передаем время жизни сессии.
6. Редирект